# Proving that $\langle X,V\rangle=\langle Y,V\rangle$ for all vectors $V\in T_pM$ $\implies$ $X=Y$

Tags: semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $(M,g)$ be a **semi-Riemannian** manifold. For $X,Y\in T_pM$, prove that if $\langle X,V\rangle=\langle Y,V\rangle$ for all vectors $V\in T_pM$, then $X=Y$.

My approach is the following: We know that the metric $g$ has to be symmetric. Hence, it can be diagonalized. Let the diagonal metric be $g'$. If the eigenvalues are all non-zero, then it is easy to see that $\langle X,V\rangle=\langle Y,V\rangle$ for all vectors $V\in T_pM$ $\implies$ $X=Y$.

However, what if one of the eigenvalues is $0$? As this is a semi-Riemannian manifold, this is possible.

Comment: Isn't the metric tensor of a semi-Riemannian manifold nondegenerate by definition?

Comment: @trii- I don't think so. Does being non-degenerate imply that all eigenvalues are non-zero?

Comment: Yes, what is your definition then?